# How do I write a program that sorts people into groups based on an input of names, and how many groups should be created?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, user-input

So I have to create a program that puts people into groups. It must:

- Ask the user how many groups they want to create
- Ask for people's names, one at a time, until the user enters 'stop' e.g there are three groups, and 5 names entered, the first person goes into the first group, the second into the second group, the third into the third group, the fourth into the first group, and the fifth into the second group. Ask the user for the number of a group. Print the people in that group, each separated by a comma and a space. Group numbers are "1-indexed" so if the user enters 1, the first group should be printed, not the second.
- Keep on asking the user for group numbers until the user enters 'stop'

This is what I have so far, but to be honest, I have no idea where to go from here, or even if this is right. I know there should be a modulo somewhere but can't figure out how to word it  (I am a beginner at this!).

```
puts "Enter the number of groups you would like to create"
group_number = gets.chomp.to_i

array = Array.new(group_number) { [] }

puts "Give me a name"
while input_name = gets.chomp
    if input == "stop"
        break
    else puts "Give me a name"
        array << input_name
    end
end
```

Comment: First change `input` to `input_name`

Answer (score 0):

> First please try to debug your code and do practice on logic part.

Try this it will print all groups with members. I enter from 'q' to 'l' from `QWERTY` keyboard as member name

```
puts "Enter the number of groups you would like to create"
group_number = gets.chomp.to_i

array = Array.new(group_number) { [] }

puts "Give me a name"
count = 0
while input_name = gets.chomp
    if input_name == "stop"
        break
    else puts "Give me a name"     
      array[count] << input_name
      count += 1
      count = 0 if count == group_number
    end
end
puts array.inspect
#[["q", "y", "a", "h"], ["w", "u", "s", "j"], ["e", "i", "d", "k"], ["r", "o", "f", "l"], ["t", "p", "g"]]
```

Above comment is the output then after that you could ask what group members you want to print

Comment: @Chloeverity If this answer solved your problem please accept/upvote this. Thanks